# fixed (byte* outBuf = outgoing)?

Tags: vb.net

can you help me to convert it to vb.net?

```
public void sendData(Byte[] outgoing)
{
    unsafe
    {
        fixed (byte* outBuf = outgoing)
        {
            if (DaliWrite(outBuf) != 65)
            {
                Error("USB Communication error (write)");
                initialised = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO, which is *not* a code writing service; please post what you have tried so far (as a [mcve]) and any issues encountered. See [ask].

Comment: For future reference, please don't submit your post without looking at the preview.  If it looks a dog's breakfast, fix before you submit.  If you don't know how to format correctly, make the effort to find out.

Comment: VB doesn't support unsafe code, so there's no direct translation.  Time for you to learn about functionality and how best to implement it in your language of choice.